# Change user's language with url parameter in Spring 3, then remove url parameter

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, redirect, locale

I have the following in my Spring 3 application-context.xml configuration so that users can change their language with a dropdown menu on any webpage

```
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="language"/>
</bean>
<bean id="localeResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.SessionLocaleResolver"/>
```

I could have that drop-down menu go to to something like `/change_language?language=ro`.  That controller would then redirect to the url in the `referer` header.  Or I could have javascript deal with this and then do a `window.location = window.location`?  How would I have javascript simply do a reload?

What's the best mechanism for dealing with user's changing their language and not having that language parameter in the URL of the current page?

Comment: Did you find answer for this problem ?

Comment: I had the drop-down menu go to the same url and my application always redirects back to itself without that language parameter.

Comment: Use Accept-Lang headers in the request for dealing with user language.